# Refresh ListView using Custom Adapter in Android

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am using Custom Adapter for `ListView`. Each `ListView` item contains `ImageButton` which will delete that Item. Now, I want to refresh full `ListView` when anyone click on `ImageButton`. How to do this ?

Or is there anyway to check `ImageButton` click on `ListView onItemClickListener` ? I have already tried notifyDataSetChanged in Custom Adapter but I can't find any changes.

**Custom Item xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightish"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgDelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Custom Adapter java :**

```
public class MyAddressesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    View vi;
    HashMap<String, String> address;

    public MyAddressesAdapter(Activity a,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arlData) {

        activity = a;
        data = arlData;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_address_view, parent, false);

        final TextView tvName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvName);

        address = new HashMap<String, String>();
        address = data.get(position);

        tvName.setText(address.get("PersonName"));

        return vi;
    }
```

**In main activity java :**

```
myAddressesAdapter = new MyAddressesAdapter(
                                    getActivity(), addressList);
                            lvMyAddresses.setAdapter(myAddressesAdapter);
```

Comment: you can put a OnClickListener on your imageButton inside the getview() of the adapter

Comment: take image button on click and set notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Show the code that deletes the item when you click the button.

Comment: Where is your OnClicklistener and how do you delete your row? Please share the relevant code!

Comment: I will update my code soon.

Answer (score 0):

put code in getview method in adapter

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               //your code here

               data.remove(position);
               notifyDataSetChanged();

           }
       });
```

Comment: what happened ? what is issue with it ? some brief would be helpful

Comment: Actually, it is removing row for sure but It keeps that row space as it is.

Comment: @JeetenParmar First of all use view holder pattern for performance and garbage collection. second check if item is removed from hashmap also b'z hashmap allows null value as well so there may be issue.

Comment: I never used view holder pattern before but I found some examples so let me change my code. I will update you soon.

Comment: I came to know about whitespace. I am using ListView inside ScrollView and so using crack to assign height. How do i prevent this ?

Comment: @JeetenParmar again call method for setting height after removing object.

Comment: But Asyncmethod is in mainactivity then how do i call it in custom adapter ?

Comment: @JeetenParmar create interface/callback between activity and adapter and call its method from adapter. implement interface in activity. so you will get callback and you can update list height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103060/discussion-between-androidnoobdev-and-jeeten-parmar).